# How to use ruby mine debugger to debug rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine, rubymine-7

I'm new to rails. The current way that I do debug on rails is:

1. Run rails in rubymine in debug mode
2. Instead of putting a break point, I will put down "binding pry" in code
3. Open terminal and type "rails c".
4. Trigger the specific state/event in terminal so I can get to the break point.

This is not my preferred workflow. It is tedious. I really like jet brain's debug mode when I can easily put down a break point, stop, evaluate expressions, look up all available objects, and step into a specific method. Is there anyway to do this with rails?

Comment: Why aren't you putting the breakpoint down, again?

Comment: so you can debug? when you put down break point, your program will stop at a specific line so you can inspect all objects.

Comment: Yes.  That's the point of the debugger.  Why *aren't* you putting the break point down?

Comment: Apologies for able to understand your question. "put down break points" means I'm setting the breakpoint mark on my IDE next to line of code so I before running that line, i would be able to enter debug mode and inspect all objects. I did put down break point, but in order to reach to those break points, I would have to trigger in terminal to trigger certain events. But when these events are being triggered, the break points doesn't break.

Comment: Clarify this in your question then - it legitimately tripped me up when you said, "Instead of putting a break point...".

Comment: That is my current work flow tho?

Answer (score 5):

So eventually I figured this out. Tools->Run Rails Console